# Launch sublime text without waiting in the terminal

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, sublime-text-2

I have installed Sublime Text 2. I downloaded it from the homepage, put it in /opt/, created a symbolic link in /usr/bin/ called `subl`. When called it correctly opens Sublime Text 2, but it also causes the terminal to wait for it to close.

How do I set it up to launch the application, and then allow me to continue working in the Terminal?

I am using Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 3):

You can add & symbol at the and of the command.

> $> subl myfile.txt &